# Randomize user name with associated job id for user

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I have two CSV files, one is with user `name,password` and other one with user name with multiple `JOB_Id` .

The the `JOB_Id` is being used for one post call and one get call.

Requirement:  When I logged in with the specific user I want the randomly associated `JOB_Id` should be selected from the other CSV file associated to that `User` (in the example I have only selected 8 `JOB_Id` but during run it would be more than 100). How to do it?

Here is my samples CSV files.
User Details Files :
[image]

JOB_Id File:
[image]

Test Plan:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is initialized when the test starts, if you want to get JOB IDs from another file dynamically - you need to switch to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)

Example setup:

1. CSV file 1, usernames.csv:

   ```
   perfuser0001
   perfuser0002
   ```
2. CSV file 2, job ids

   - perfuser0001.csv

     ```
     perfuser0001-job-id-1
     perfuser0001-job-id-2
     ```
   - perfuser0002.csv

     ```
     perfuser0002-job-id-1
     perfuser0002-job-id-2
     ```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)

Also [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so please consider migrating from Beanshell on next available opportunity.

Comment: One quick question, how to set a location in the __CSVRead() ?